# Cron jobs not executing command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, backup

I'm trying to schedule backups using cron jobs [as explained here](http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/scheduling-backups/).

The cron jobs do run but sadly don't execute the command inside it.

This is my schedule.rb file

```
every 1.minute do
   command "backup perform -t my_backup"
end
```

Which translates to this cron file:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/roy/Backup/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t my_backup'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/roy/Backup/config/schedule.rb
```

The cron jobs then run every minute (I can see that by running `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`). These are my last cron jobs:

```
Mar 20 21:48:01 roybuntu CRON[18041]: (roy) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t my_backup')
Mar 20 21:48:01 roybuntu CRON[18040]: (roy) MAIL (mailed 37 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Mar 20 21:49:01 roybuntu CRON[18063]: (roy) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t my_backup')
Mar 20 21:49:01 roybuntu CRON[18062]: (roy) MAIL (mailed 37 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

I also installed postfix because earlier I got "No MTA installed" error messages in the example above. However this didn't fix it.

Anyone familiar with this problem and/or know how to fix it?

**EDIT:**
Also running the cron file as a root user doesn't seem to work. I used `sudo crontab -e` to edit the root cron file.

This is the output when running the `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` command after I added a root crontab:

```
Mar 21 19:36:01 roybuntu CRON[9387]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t my_backup')
Mar 21 19:36:01 roybuntu CRON[9388]: (roy) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t my_backup')
Mar 21 19:36:01 roybuntu CRON[9385]: (roy) MAIL (mailed 37 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Mar 21 19:36:01 roybuntu CRON[9386]: (root) MAIL (mailed 90 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

Comment: What happens when you run `/bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t my_backup'` directly on the server?

Comment: @BryantJackson This will successfully perform the backup, so the command itself works

Comment: Interesting, so the command on its own operates exactly as expected, but running the cronjob causes it to fail. Without knowing whats in your backup command, I would recommend fiddling with the timing. Calling the cronjob every minute may be causing you issues. Honestly just a guess though. Maybe set it to every 10 minutes and come back in 20 or so min.

Comment: @BryantJackson Sadly, this doesn't work either

Comment: Have you try specify user-name in your crontab? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81814/13082

Comment: @KenRatanachaiS. Yes, that also doesn't change the outcome :/

Comment: What logger are you using http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/logging/ and what is the output?

Comment: @Anthony I haven't configured any loggers manually. But there is a backup.log in the folder where I configured my Backup. The only backups logged are the ones I did manually.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try running the cron task command as the same user as your application? It may not have the permission to run that command.

Comment: Good catch; _who_ is running the cronjob, good very well be the source of the issue.

Comment: I also tried using `sudo crontab -e`, instead of `crontab -e`. This edits the cron file which runs as root. I also inserted the command here, and my cron job does run as root but still doesn't create a backup file

Comment: Did you configure the Notifier::Mail correctly like it shows in the guides for the Backup gem. [link](http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/notifier-mail/).

Comment: @JollyProgrammer No, I haven't configured that file, because I don't need to be notified via mail. Or is this a necessary thing I need to configure for this to work?

Comment: It seems like it needs to as it is predefined to send an email everytime the backup finishes successfully. Check it here: http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/notifier-mail/